# After Parsing a JSON string to become an object how do you access those properites?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

So I parsed a string to turn it inton an object. Now after trying to access the properties in that object to display an input I get the error`property does not exist on type string` I am reaally using a service but for simplicity purposes I manually made a JSON string.

```
info: string = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":3, "e":4}}'
dataTodisplay: string;

 ngOnInit() {
 console.log(typeof this.info); //string
 this.info= JSON.parse(this.info);
 console.log(typeof this.info); //object
 this.dataToDisply = this.info.a; //error 'a' does not exist on type string
}
```

Comment: Your parsed `Json` is in `this.x`. So `this.x.a` will work,

Comment: That was just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring your variable as `any`, right now you have declared it as `string` so it can only contain a string property.

```
info: any = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":3, "e":4}}'
```